# Use concentration of a blending as a constraint on a linear optimization

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, or-tools

I have the following table, from which a have to create a recipe with a specific value for  protein and carbohydrates.

[image]

And using or-tools to solve this problem, so far I have:

The formated data

```
data = [
['f1', 10, 15, 17, 10],
['f2', 2, 11, 12, 14],
['f3', 6.5, 17, 16, 13],
['f4', 8, 12, 8, 16]
]
```

The constraines for the nutriends:

nutrients = [
    ["protein",15.5],
    ["carbohydrates",12.3]]

The objective function, where the upper bound "data[i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXdhI.png)" is the stock of that particular element.

```
food = [[]] * len(data)

# Objective: minimize the sum of (price-normalized) foods.
objective = solver.Objective()
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    food[i] = solver.NumVar(0.0, data[i][1], data[i][0])
    objective.SetCoefficient(food[i], 4)
objective.SetMinimization()
```

I also have the as constrain the required value of each nutrient:

```
constraints = [0] * (len(nutrients))
for i in range(0, len(nutrients)):
    constraints[i] = solver.Constraint(nutrients[i][1], solver.infinity())
    for j in range(0, len(data)):
        constraints[i].SetCoefficient(food[j], data[j][i+3])
```

And finally the solver:

status = solver.Solve()

```
if status == solver.OPTIMAL:
    # Display the amounts (in dollars) to purchase of each food.
    price = 0
    num_nutrients = len(data[i]) - 3
    nutrients = [0] * (len(data[i]) - 3)
    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        price += food[i].solution_value()

        for nutrient in range(0, num_nutrients):
            nutrients[nutrient] += data[i][nutrient+3] * food[i].solution_value()

        if food[i].solution_value() > 0:
            print ("%s = %f" % (data[i][0], food[i].solution_value()))

    print ('Optimal  price: $%.2f' % (price))
else:  # No optimal solution was found.
    if status == solver.FEASIBLE:
        print ('A potentially suboptimal solution was found.')
    else:
        print ('The solver could not solve the problem.')
```

Which up to this part is working fine, the result I get is the following:

```
f1 = 0.077049
f3 = 0.886885
Optimal  price: $0.96
```

Know I need to add as well the constraints of how many kg I will make, which have to satisfy the previous constraints as well.

My first guess was to add a multiplier to the nutrients requirement

```
factor = 10
nutrients = [
    ["protein",15.5*factor],
    ["carbohydrates",12.3*factor]]
```

Tjis way I will have 10 times more food, but then I realized that this is not correct, since what I need is a concentración E.G.

I need 10kg with 15.5 protein/kg and 12.3 carbohydrates/kg 
the constrain I need is something like this:

```
(f1*W + f2*X + f3*Y + f4*Z)/(W+X+Y+Z) = 10kg with  15.5 protein/kg and 12.3 carbohydrates/kg 

Where W, X, Y and Z are the kg of each food
```

How can I add this constrain to solver?

Answer (score 2):

```
(f1*W + f2*X + f3*Y + f4*Z)/(W+X+Y+Z) = 10
```

is the same as

```
f1*W + f2*X + f3*Y + f4*Z = 10*(W+X+Y+Z)
```

This is now linear.

And, in case we missed some math classes, we can write this as a standard LP constraint:

```
(f1-10)*W + (f2-10)*X + (f3-10)*Y + (f4-10)*Z = 0
```

Comment: And you can look at the stiedler diet example in the documentation, we have implemented a problem similar to this one IMHO